# How to save a sub-entity of an entity using spring-data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to do an assignment using Spring Boot and spring-data.
I have 2 entities Organization and Location.

1.Organization

```
public class Organization {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Location location;
}

public class Location {
    private Double lattitude;
    private Double longitude;
}
```

And my database table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE organization (
    id int primary key,
    organization_name varchar(255),
    organization_location_lat double,
    organization_location_long double
)
```

Now I am using spring data to persist this entity in database.In normal scenario just invoking the save(Organization org) method would persist the data but I am not sure how to store the organization data with the location.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities have an identity . Embeddables have no identity of their own and can only be queried for using the owning entities.

you Organization  is `@Entity` lication should be `@Embeddable`(as there is no id , and it's part of `Organization` table).

But , I think it's not your case according to your table ,if Location is just part a of `Organization` and doen't have own lifecycle (exists only inside Organization) . If Location has lifecycle outside the `Organization`  it should be entity (then should be id for `Location` as for entity) and you need relationship between `Organization` and `Location` , dependence on case how you use is , like one-to-one or many to one and use sascade type for location

```
public class Organization {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    private Location location;
}

@Embeddable
public class Location {
    private Double lattitude;
    private Double longitude;
}
```

see example https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/embeddables.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!!
In my case location is part of organization, it won't have idependant existence of its own, however it will be part of few other entities as well such as car,person etc.So I assume @Embeddable is applicable in all these cases as well?

Comment: yes, it's applicable. I wrote about @entity for location as in common case :) we start with Embeddable at the beggining , and after couple months move to separate entity as we get ,for that moment ,  we have a lot data duplicate for location.

Comment: few other entities as well such as car,person etc. - think about create base class with location and extends from it , if it's acceptable for you